# Can we add or remove bones to a Metarig with Rigify add-on?

Tags: rigging, bones, rigify

I'm adjusting a metarig (a skeleton) for a bipedal character mesh with the Rigify add-on. But I want to remove the metarig's bones for the face and add some bones for the feet (my character has long floppy flippers).

My question is: With Rigify, can we add or remove bones to the original skeleton without breaking the rig's widgets before or after we push the button "Generate rig" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is yes. The process is a bit more involved if you want to use all the features.

To delete the face, highlight/delete all the face bones, including a bone inside the head called "face". I suggest you hide the head bone,  or "spine 06" in 2.79, box-select, delete and unhide.

For the toes, add them as children of the "Toe" bones. For the extra functionality, you will want to:

- *Pose Mode* > select the root of each toe bone you just created
- In the *Bone Properties Panel* and find *Rigify Type* (bottom panel) you can choose *limbs.simple_tentacle*, *limbs.super_finger* or *basic.copy_chain*.
- In that same panel, choose the layer where you want the Tweak Bones to be. You can look them up in *Object Mode* under the *Data Panel > Rigify Layer Names*

Comment: Cool thank you ! I have tested it and it's working. After I've posted my question, I've found also a video that can help to illustrate the different panels to use: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bI_qdzpg1CQ

Comment: Yes DanPro is most excellent!