# Can metarig support adding some extra bones to it?

Tags: rigify, inverse-kinematics

I already saw [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106358/can-we-add-or-remove-bones-to-a-metarig-with-rigify-add-on) because it showed as a similar question. My use case is, I need to add bones between the limbs, like an extra bone between the shoulder and the bicep. I already have a custom rig, but found out that it was quite a hassle to make it work, just from the fact that I don't want those in-between extra bones to move/rotate most of the time. So now I'm thinking of using metarig and modify it because maybe it could handle my use case and have the ik and stuff automated for me

Comment: It is possible. Actually, you can create any type of rig you want with the rigify addon. There is an excelent tutorials playlist on youtube called Rig anything with rigify by CGdive. You should check it out.

Comment: Ok, will check that out

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka Thank you for the mention. I am biased for sure but that's what I would recommend too :)

Comment: @CGDive, didn't expect you to pop up here ! Thanks for everything and keep up the good work !